# Springboot Quartz: clustered mode ignored?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm getting this log when my spring boot starts:

```
Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.
```

As you can see:

- `'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'`
- `**LocalDataSourceJobStore**' - which supports persistence. and is **clustered**`

Why `NON_CLUSTERED` appears, when scheduler is clustered mode?

My related properties:

```yaml
spring:
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    properties:
      org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
      org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
      org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us all properties? probably it is being overriten. Did you add `org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO` ? also what you are referring they are two different concepts, but anyways try it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was only Instance name. Try to write property org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO and check the result.